# Identifier missing in attributes inspector xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode version 4.6+ doesn't have the field for setting a `storyboard view controller identifier` in the attributes inspector tab.

Where can I find it?

It used to be in the attributes inspector, like so:

[image]

But now there is only the Title field left:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found out that in xcode 4.5 the identifier is replaced by Identity > **Storyboard ID**, which is now in the identity inspector.

You can see the field below:

[image]