# How to instantiate a ViewController programmatically since XCode 4.5 does not have ViewController Identifier?

Tags: xcode4, uiviewcontroller, ios6

I need to instantiate a `ViewController` programmatically using Storyboard, because this ViewController is only called conditionally (It is loaded when a `UIBarButtonItem` is present, which is conditional).

I understand that I can do this by calling this method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` from `UIStoryboard`, as directed by this [Apple Developer Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html) (see under **Instantiating a Storyboard’s View Controller Programmatically**).

This is all well and good until I'm stuck with the `identifier`, because XCode 4.5 Interface Builder does not have an `identifier` attribute under the Attributes Inspector. It only has the Storyboard ID under the Identity Inspector, which doesn't really help.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: [These][1] [answers][2] seems to suggest they're the same thing.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471429/uipageviewcontroller-using-storyboard-and-xcode-4-5

  [2]:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575342/identifier-missing-in-attributes-inspector-xcode

Comment: Yes, that seemed to work! Thank you!